# Open or Save prompt in Tabletools

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, tabletools

I am using Tabletools plugin for DataTable for Exporting the Report in PDF/Excel.

Here, I can only able to get the **"save as"** dialog box, to Save the exported file.

However, I need to configure my code to prompt me a **"Open or Save prompt"** rather **"Save as"** dialog

I need the below prompt to be appeared,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems we can't do this functionality in TableTools plugin.

Reference,

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/78891#Comment_78891